# Find specific cell of a celltable with Selenium xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a celltable , where i have multiple rows and is a dynamic table,

Screenshot attached ..

[image]

What i want is to find the row where column contains useren@lim.mobi
and then click its checkBox.

I am trying with xpath but not much experience here , If i can get some help please

Thanks

Here is the html code of the specific cell

[image]

Comment: Share Html code for the same.

Comment: screenshot of html code attached

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact html of your table to form an xpath would be difficult. 
however it should look something like this

```
//*[contains(text(),'useren@lim.mobi ')]/../td[2]
```

for following table, if I have to find the corrosponding contact for some company, This is how I would do it. 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

```
//*[contains(text(),'Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti')]/../td[2]
```

Comment: thanks for the example, i added screenshot, please guide.

Comment: the answer suggest by anderson will work perfectly. 
`//td[contains(text(), "useren@lim.mobi")]/following::input[type="checkbox"]`

Comment: its giving me null

Comment: isnt it possible to use the one u suggested, because i want to click on the 1st and 3rd checkbox of this row..

Comment: @junaidp it it's possible, you just gotta figure out the answer, I showed you the way how to form an xpath for similar situation. don't expect direct answers from this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following xpath:

```
//tr[./td[contains(text(),'useren@lim.mobi')]/td[2]/input
```

if above xpath is not working please attach html code screenshot so i can tell you the extact xpath.

Comment: //tr[./td/div/a[contains(text(),'<useren@lim.mobi>')]]/td[2]/div/input             please use this one and let me know if it's not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might help to solve your issue:

```
//td[@title="useren@lim.mobi"]/following::input[@type="checkbox"]
```

If you get `NoSuchElementException` with this `XPath` you might need to add `ExplicitWait` as below:

```
WebElementWait wait = new WebElementWait(getWebDriver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[@title='useren@lim.mobi']/following::input[@type='chec‌​k‌​b‌​ox']")));
```

Comment: Hi screenshot of corresponding html code attached , please guide

Comment: If provided `XPath` doesn't work, share `selenium` exception as well

Comment: am i using the correct xpath : //td[@title=useren@lim.mobi]/following::input[type=checkbox]  ::::: because it says "not a valid xpath xpression"

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException) org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression (//td[@title=useren@lim.mobi]/following::input[type=checkbox]) because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '(//td[@title=useren@lim.mobi]/following::input[type=checkbox])' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Are you sure you use quotes around values? You seem to use `//td[@title=useren@lim.mobi]/following::input[type=checkbox‌​]` instead of `//td[@title="useren@lim.mobi"]/following::input[type="checkbox"]`

Comment: if i use as is , i get compilation error, here's the screenshot...   https://www.screencast.com/t/OBmnGe31EZAl

Comment: I see... This is because of inconsistent quotes usage. Just replace double quotes with single quotes as `"//td[@title='useren@lim.mobi']/following::input[type='checkb‌​ox']"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139261/discussion-between-junaidp-and-andersson).

Comment: now it says ::   (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException) org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[@title='useren@lim.mobi']/following::input[type='check‌​b‌​ox']"}

Comment: Oh... sorry. My fault :) I forgot to add `@` to `type`... try `"//td[@title='useren@lim.mobi']/following::input[@type='check‌​b‌​ox']"`. This should finally find required checkbox

Comment: thanks :( ,but it still says :   (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException) org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[@title='useren@lim.mobi']/following::input[@type='chec‌​k‌​b‌​ox']"}

Comment: as in the screenshot i provided in the beginning , u see there are more than 1 matches for useren@lim.mobi, and for the first one there is no checkbox infront of that , checkbox is infront of the last one.. may be we could get the last match or useren@lim.mobi..

Comment: No. It's not the cause of exception. Also note that `//*[contains(text(), 'useren@lim.mobi')]` and `//td[@title='useren@lim.mobi']` is not the same, so I don't think that it might also match 3 elements...Try to use updated answer

Comment: Thanks for this much time , :( but still no luck , i even wait for 50 secs,  but it still says Element not found. Also i tried on XpatHelper plugin, you can see the screenshot , it also says NULL..   https://www.screencast.com/t/2a0GOl3I

Comment: Try to remove that `[last()]` or use it as `"//td[@title='useren@lim.mobi'][last()]/following::input[@type='chec‌​k‌​b‌​ox']"`

Comment: tried , but same ... i think this isnt possible, we can leave it here , took ur lot of time,